how can i call my function with XMLHttpRequest
hello i need to call my function without reload the page
there is my code
test.php:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function say() {

        alert('hello');
    }
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="module">
    function test(){
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function (){
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        xhttp.open("GET","live.php");
        xhttp.send();
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        test();
    },3000);
</script>

live.php:
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", say);
</script>

i also try this in live.php:
<script>
    say()
</script>

i need alert work without reload the page
thanks and sorry for my english

script tags loaded by changing innerHTML are not processed/executed - also, the window load event won't fire a second time

here is a function I wrote many years ago (so it probably could be improved) that you can use to load the html fragment onto the target element and have the scripts execute

It's the 2020's. Time to learn fetch() instead of XMLHttpRequest.
